# Как зарегистрировать кастомный маршрут в WordPress, например, http://site.ru/register?

Tags: wordpress, rest, route

Как зарегистрировать кастомный маршрут в WordPress, например, `http://site.ru/register`?

Нужен способ, позволяющий добавить маршрут именно для того, чтобы отобразить свой вид по этому запросу.

То что я хочу, на примере laravel будет выглядеть так:

```
Route:get("/register", "RegisterController@index");
```

И мы получаем колбек в методе index класса RegisterController, где можем выполнить любое действие и что угодно отобразить.

**Есть ли возможность получить что-то подобное в вордпресе?**

Будет что-то на подобии `site.ru/voting/{voting_category}/{name}/{other_queries}`. У плагина свои таблицы в БД и, например, по запросу url `site.ru/voting/` отбработает `"SELECT * FROM 'voting'"`, а если запрос будет `site.ru/voting/sport/football/`, то нужен будет запрос `"SELECT * FROM voting WHERE category = 'sport' AND name = 'football'` и т.д. Это просто пример, чтобы была понятна идея.

Как мне получить колбек по отпределённому URL и из этого колбека подключить шаблон, в котором отработает результат запроса? Ну как-то так...

Comment: Не надо подходить к WP с известным вам стандартом. MVC и EDA - разные архитектуры. Никаких маршрутов (за исключением REST API) и callbacks (только в хуках). В WP вы можете создать страницу со слагом register и вывести на неё все, что захотите. Если этого мало - назначьте странице шаблон (файл .php) и выводите там контент любой сложности. Если и страницу в БД создавать не хотите, можно обрабатывать /register "на лету" и выводить туда любой результат работы php.

Comment: Нет не все так просто, кастомные маршруты нужны для плагина, я привел register для понимания вопроса. На самом деле будет что-то на подобии site.ru/voting/{voting_category}/{name}/{other_queries} У плагина свои таблицы в БД и например по запросу url site.ru/voting/ отбработает "SELECT * FROM 'voting'" а если запрос будет site.ru/voting/sport/football/ То нужен будет запрос "SELECT * FROM voting WHERE category = 'sport' AND name = 'football' и т.д. Это просто пример что бы вы поняли идею

Comment: Никаких проблем.

Comment: Я не пойму как мне по определенному запросу получить колбек из которого я смогу загрузить шаблон, ну или что-то такое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в ваш плагин следующий код:

```
/**
 * Template for the dynamic page.
 */
function dynamic_page() {
    $page_slug = 'register';
    $uri       = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path      = wp_parse_url( $uri, PHP_URL_PATH );

    if ( '/' . trailingslashit( $page_slug ) === trailingslashit( $path ) ) {
        get_header();
        // Output here any content.
        get_footer();
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'dynamic_page' );
```

По событию init WordPress проверяет, какой url обрабатывается. Если `http://site.ru/register`, то срабатывает if, в котором выводится хедер и футер страницы (если нужно) и между ними - любой произвольный контент, созданный php.

Если нужно выводить breamcrumbs от Yoast, то добавьте такой хук:

```
/**
 * @param array $crumbs The crumbs array.
 *
 * @return array
 */
function wpseo_breadcrumb_links( $crumbs ) {
    $page_slug = 'register';
    $uri       = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $path      = wp_parse_url( $uri, PHP_URL_PATH );

    if ( '/' . trailingslashit( $page_slug ) === trailingslashit( $path ) ) {
        $crumbs[1]['text'] = 'Ваше название страницы';

        return $crumbs;
    }

    return $crumbs;
}
```

Comment: Частично решает проблему, но не уверен что работает на 100% правильно, т.к. например админбар не выводится по видимому он формируется на другом хуке. Возможно еще что-то не отрабатывает. Но как вариант хорошее предложение спасибо.

Comment: Я пока в процессе разбирался с этим наше хороший плагин WP_Router вот он решает эту проблему, хороший плагин. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-router/

Comment: @Pavel в вопросе про wpadminbar не было ни слова. Если он нужен (как и всё остальное), то надо использовать не `init`, а `template_redirect`. Остальной код не меняется.

Comment: @Pavel а вот использовать окаменелый плагин 6-летней давности, не проверенный с последними 3 основными выпусками WordPress - не хорошее, а очень плохое решение. В нём может быть произвольное количество дыр безопасности и несовместимостей с текущей версией WP.

Comment: Понял спасибо  за помощь

Comment: кстати вот пользовался для этого дела init хуком а сейчас попробовал второй вариант template_redirect и получаю title - Страница не найдена. Может хук не тот?

Comment: Разумеется, не тот. Я вам указал правильный.

Comment: Нет вы не поняли, я вешаю на хук - `template_redirect` тот колбек который вы писали выше и получаю в тайтле "Страница не найдена", это нормальное поведение?

Comment: Скорее всего вы получаете это не в заголовке страницы, потому что `the_title()` в такой ситуации выводит пустую строку. Возможно, это сообщение у вас в Breadcrumbs, причём установлен Yoast SEO, так?

Comment: Да Yoast установлен, сейчас я протестирую этот хук на чистом вп. Мне скоро понадобится писать проект в котором будут задействованы кастомные таблицы в бд работа с которыми будет посредством глобального объекта wpdb, в общем выборка будет происходить через свои SQL запросы. Так вот во фронте нужно подобрать нормальный способ по созданию роутов, по переходу на который будет выводиться определенный контент привязанный к определенному роуту, пагинация и другое.

Comment: Добавил вам хук для вывода breadcrumbs под Yoast

Comment: KAGG Design, бредкрамбс я пока не трогал, сейчас я получаю в заголовке страницы "Страница не найдета" в теге тайтл. Получается мне придется развесить хуки на тайтл, дескрипшн и прочее связанное с хедером?

Comment: Ну и помимо всего я получаю ошибку 404 - http://joxi.ru/V2V7oyhxgDYYAv

Comment: Или нужно предварительно создать страницу?

Comment: Не нужно создавать страницу. Вы что-то делаете неправильно. Вот вам пример страницы, созданной "на лету", тем самым кодом, что в ответе: http://test.kagg.eu/notifications Откройте networks - 200

Comment: А вы какой хук используете `init` или `template_redirect` ? На хуке `init` все ок

Comment: На тестовом сайте хук `init`. Да, admin_bar при этом не выводится