# Разные урлы, разный контент, один single-page WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Имею сайт на WordPress, есть API турагенства.
на главной странице циклом `for` показываю информацию до 6 горящих туров в виде блоков. Мне нужно, что при клике на каждый блок,открывался `single-page` с одинаковой разметкой для каждого блока, но с разной информацией и соответственно `url`!
На подобии, если бы у меня была архивная страница и на ней я показывал `single` посты.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вообщем, решил задачу следующим способом, может кому то будет полезным:
Создал 2 страницы `hot-tours` и `tour`, первая страница является якобы архивной страницей, вторая дочерняя - single.
С помощью `add_query_arg` задаю параметры для для ранее созданной страницы

```
$arr_params = array('key' => $tour_key[$i]);
$new_url = esc_url(add_query_arg($arr_params, 'http://localhost:3000/hot-tours/tour/'));
```

Получаем вот такой URL - `http://localhost:3000/hot-tours/tour/?key=123` отдельно для каждого блока отдельные значение для ключа `key`. 
Соответственно страница с шаблоном у нас одна - это `hot-tours/tour/` но контент разный и url тоже, благодаря параметрам которые передаю через `add_query_arg`.
Ну и дальше через `query_vars` достаем ключ и по нему уже делаем запрос к API и вытаскиваем нужную инфу для каждого тура.

Comment: Если вам нужны динамические страницы с произвольными именами, можете воспользоваться моим ответом на эту тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/922415/220220

Answer (score 1):

Создайте 6 страниц под 6 горящих туров, задайте им один и тот же шаблон. Они будут иметь разные url.

Подробнее о создании шаблонов в WordPress: https://wp-kama.ru/id_5177/3-sposoba-sozdat-shablon-stranitsyi.html

Comment: Не вариант, страница должна быть одна, с разным контентом, может быть такое, что в будущем будем 4 блока, а потом 15 и т.д.

Comment: Что значит - "страница должна быть одна, с разным контентом"? Как вы себе это представляете в админке? А базе? Похоже, вы не совсем четко понимаете, чего вы хотите.

Comment: Возможно я неправильно выразился, но создавать страницы для каждого тура - бред, сейчас их одно количество, завтра - другое. Нужно как то сделать перезапись ссылки, в которой будет передаваться какое-то значение (например айди), а на страницу будет отображаться тот контент который соответствует этому айди!